# Can multiple user profiles see each others' data or photos?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, multi-user

Some specific cases:

- What about browsing the drive when connected to a computer via USB?
- Is the owner profile able to see other users' data or photos?

In my basic tests, it seems that the user data and photos are isolated when using USB MTP connection. But what if a user installs a File Manager app? Or is there a way to do USB Mass Storage that would expose all the data for all users?